# Make an updatable file to hold the connection string in ASP-Classic

Tags: database, asp-classic, odbc, connection-string

I have an `asp` file which contains a `connectionString` to my database.

I'm wondering if there is a way to change that information before the user try to log on the system.

I named it `_conn.asp` and it contains the following asp code

```
dim conn

sub OpenConn()
    Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Conn.Open = "Driver=driver_name; SERVER=server_name; uid=user_name; pwd=user_pwd; DATABASE=db_name;"
End sub

Sub CloseConn()
    Conn.Close
    Set Conn = Nothing
End sub
```

I want to be able to change the `driver`, `server`, `uid`, `pwd` and `database` information inside that asp file.

First I realized that an xml file would be the best choice but then I heard about a bunch of security problems involving putting a connectionString on a xml file.

If it is not possible to update the `_conn.asp` file, what would be the best practice to make an updatable file to hold the `connectionString` to a database in classic ASP?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would put the connection string into a separate file in the directory not listed in IIS. Say, your ASP pages in Website\Scripts folder. Create a new folder Website\Includes. make sure it is not listed. Create a file, say DSN.inc inside this folder.

Now, in your asp pages add this line:

```
<!-- #include FILE="../Includes/dsn.inc" -->
```

DSN.inc would contain the connection string (here is an example of Jet4.0 connection string)

```
  set rs=Server.CreateObject("adodb.Recordset")
  sDSN = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath ("..\Databases\db.mdb") & "; "
```

In your ASP pages just re-use `rs`

Comment: Thanks man. But if I want to change these information just before the user try to log on the system? I mean, pretending I have a form where I (as administrator) could change `driver`, `server`, `uid`, `pwd` and `database` information, how could it be updated on the `<!-- #include FILE="../Includes/dsn.inc" -->` you said?